# .htaccess ignore certain directories but pass subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## existing .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if not https, redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# parse the subdomain as a variable we can access
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?sub=%1

# ignore any .cfm|.html|.asp|.ico files and certain directories
RewriteRule ^(php|images|css|js|xyz|(.*)\.php|(.*)\.html|(.*)\.asp|(.*)\.ico)($|/) - [L]

# map all requests to the 'path' get variable in index.cfm
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

=======

```
currently its doing this:

https://hello.domain.com --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello
https://hello.domain.com/dir1/15 --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php?path=dir1/15&sub=hello
https://hello.domain.com/index.php --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php
https://hello.domain.com/images/logo.png --> https://hello.domain.com/images/logo.png

what needs to happen:

1. https://hello.domain.com/index.php --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello
```

(currently sub=hello is not being appended)

```
2. https://hello.domain.com/process/generate.php --> https://hello.domain.com/process/generate.php?sub=hello
```

("/process" directory needs to be ignored, but "sub=hello" still needs to be passed)

Basically all i need some additions to the rules to make sure #1 & #2 are also working. No changes of existing rules should happen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if not https, redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ignore any .cfm|.html|.asp|.ico files and certain directories
RewriteRule ^(php|images|css|js|xyz|(.*)\.html|(.*)\.asp|(.*)\.ico)($|/) - [L]

# parse the subdomain as a variable we can access
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sub=%1&path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is an internal variable that is set to 200 after first internal rewrite.

Comment: It almost did it. But now I get this: https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello&sub=hello

Comment: It did fix that problem, but now something else is not working. hello.domain.com/about/a.php is supposed to be hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello&path=about/a.php, but it is missing "path=about/a.php"

Comment: ok, much better but still not quite. Two conditions are not met. 1. any folder that is not listed in the ignore rule needs to go to "index.php", for instance: https://hello.domain.com/about/a.php needs to be https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello&path=about/a.php

Comment: 2. for https://hello.domain.com it needs not to repeat things twice. Right now i get this: https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=demo&path=index.php&sub=demo&path=

Comment: it broke this: https://hello.domain.com/about/a.php is supposed to be: https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello&path=/about/a.php. Instead i am getting this: https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=demo&path=index.php&sub=demo&path=about/a.php

Comment: Also, can we add one additional rule: I need to specify some folders that need to be ignored but the "sub=hello" still needs to be added. For instance: https://hello.domain.com/process/general.php still needs to be https://hello.domain.com/process/general.php?sub=hello. So, the rule would be for the /process folder

Comment: sorry, take (.*)\.php out... in my code i am just ignoring the /php folder

Comment: I updated your answer with the full .htaccess that works for every condition except that it adds "sub=hello" twice in certain conditions: https://hello.domain.com/about/a.php -- becomes this -- https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello&path=about/a.php&sub=hello

Comment: Your previous version that you posted did not work very well, so I reverted back to your original answer. BTW, I do not have any other code in the .htaccess file other than what we are discussing

Comment: ALMOST THERE! Only one condition is not working. for https://hello.domain.com i still get QUERY_STRING=sub=hello&sub=hello

Comment: No I am not getting that in my testing. I just get `QUERY_STRING=sub=hello&path=`